# Flutter: duplicate notifyListeners()

Tags: flutter

I use a provider to share my global information across my app. Sometimes I need to update the UI with `notifyListeners()` but I end up calling different functions with a `notifyListeners()` on each of them.

In terms of performance, am I doing something wrong here? Should I cancel all of these `notifyListeners()`s and leave only the last one maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing right. For each method with a `notifyListener()` you call it every time you need. You may have as much methods as you want with `notifyListener()`. However, where do you put the `Provider` in the widget tree, and where do you put the `Consumer` is the real issue in terms of performance.

Comment: The provider wraps the main widget

Comment: Sometimes I get "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build" when I have these extra notifyListeners()

Comment: https://medium.com/@aruny3/how-to-use-changenotifier-in-flutter-440371617b8c "be sure not to wrap any of the widgets with ChangeNotifierProvider if they don’t need it". Does it mean I am following a bad practic?

Comment: Hi Dani, if you always wrap the main widget with a provider (example: ChangeNotifierProvider) this is not a good practise. Since ChangeNotifierProvider is the widget that provides an instance of a ChangeNotifier to its descendants, put the provider widget just above where it will be required.

Comment: got it. I followed a tutorial that did exactly the same thing but I also saw some other approaches as you mentioned. Not something easy to refactor at this point but I guess I'll have to change it. Thanks

Comment: Interesting video about this topic: https://youtu.be/NeAMD0lQ5jw